How does onSnapshot on firebase/firestore work?
I'm new with firebase. I'm building a simple app with Vuejs and Firebase by following a Udemy course.
I'm curious about a strange thing. I'm trying to understand but I can't.
I know, the onChange event is always running. With old version, when I logout and loggin with other user. The data still belong to the privous user
old version
    async getNotes() {
      this.notesLoaded = false
      onSnapshot(notesCollectionQuery, (querySnapshot) => {
        let notes = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          let note = {
            id: doc.id,
            content: doc.data().content,
            date: doc.data().date
          }
          notes.push(note)
        })
        this.notes = notes
        this.notesLoaded = true
      })
    },

new version will fix that issue.
      if (getNotesSnapshot) getNotesSnapshot() // unsubscribe from any active listener

      getNotesSnapshot = onSnapshot(notesCollectionQuery, (querySnapshot) => {
        let notes = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          let note = {
            id: doc.id,
            content: doc.data().content,
            date: doc.data().date
          }
          notes.push(note)
        })
        this.notes = notes
        this.notesLoaded = true
      })
    },

How it achieve that? Thanks.
Full code is available here
